# reversing extraposition

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dummy-it, extraposition

Let’s as­sume we have this sen­tence:

> It was the in­ven­tion of the hand-held cal­cu­la­tor that
> pro­vided the orig­i­nal tech­nol­ogy for the present
> gen­er­a­tion of small but pow­er­ful com­put­ers.

I al­ready know that the word *It* is a “dummy” and here we have
ex­tra­po­si­tional trans­for­ma­tion, which means we can
replace *It* with the *that*-clause from the end of the
sen­tence. But if we do this, then the *that*-clause is
miss­ing its sub­ject:

> That pro­vided the orig­i­nal tech­nol­ogy for the present
> gen­er­a­tion of small but pow­er­ful com­put­ers was the
> in­ven­tion of the hand-held cal­cu­la­tor.

Re­cently I viewed a course about trans­for­ma­tional
gram­mar which men­tioned that when a rel­a­tive clause is
used as an NP (sub­ject or ob­ject of the sen­tence), the
rel­a­tive clause should con­tain all parts of the
sen­tence, in­clud­ing sub­ject, ob­ject, and so on.

But in the sen­tence above, we see how the sub­ject in the
*that pro­vided* part has been omit­ted.

Which one is wrong? The sen­tence I re­versed from
ex­tra­po­si­tional trans­for­ma­tion, or the rule
which was on that course?

Comment: The sentence is just a variation of: The invention of the hand-held calculator provided the original technology for the present generation of small but powerful computers.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you for your response. I know that this sentence is another variation of that, but I want to clarify my understanding in the extra position rule. I want to know what is the correct form of the reversion.
do we need subject or not?

Comment: There may be a problem with the premise of the question. In your example, the pronoun "it" doesn't refer to the "that" clause. It refers to the other nominative of the equative, namely "the invention ...". So you can't replace "it" with the "that" clause in your sentence transformation if you want to retain the original semantics.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually _It_ in this sentence doesn't refer to anything because it is dummy as I mentioned in the question. 
After reversion it will be omitted. the only reason _It_ exists in the sentence is that the syntax of the sentence will be ok. [Lawrence](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/142322/lawrence)

Comment: Your example is not an extrapostion construction.

Comment: Are you sure? @BillJ
because I viewed it in some sort of video course.
would you please explain more?

Comment: Your example is not an extrapostion construction since the _that_ clause is not a potential replacement for "it". It's actually a relative clause with _in­ven­tion of the hand-held cal­cu­la­tor_ as antecedent.

Comment: as far as I know the only places which we can have a cataphora is in adverbial sentences and in prepositional phrases. (in which reference of the pronoun comes after the pronoun)
since sentence above is neither of them therefore I think _It_ should be dummy.
If what you say is correct it should be another form of cataphora? @BillJ

Comment: I'd say that it's an _it_- cleft construction, the basic version of which is: _The invention of the hand-held calculator pro­vided the original technology for the present generation of small but powerful computers_. In the cleft version, "it" is a dummy subject, and the relative clause appears in extranuclear position at the end.

Comment: Thanks  for your response a lot. I'm not familiar with that construction I'll try to study that to understand whether this problem is going to solve or not?
Is that construction exists in transformational grammar? @BillJ

Comment: @BillJ is right. _It_-clefts use a dummy _it_ like extraposition does, and they also move stuff, but they add a dummy _be_ to serve as the fulcrum of cleavage, so _X did Y_ becomes _It was X that did Y_, or _It was Y that X did_, depending on what you want to stress. There are also _Wh-_ clefts, like _What X did was Y_.

Comment: Thanks to both of you BillJ and @jlawler Im new to this website if any of you post this as answer i wil accept that. Thanks again

Comment: The Fulcrum of Cleavage. It's _got_ to be the next Bond film.

Comment: You are confusing a *that*-clause, which functions like a noun (*It bothers me that you are here —> That you are here bothers me.*) with an *it*-cleft, where *that* is a relative pronoun heading a relative clause. (*It was the calculator that added the numbers. —> The calculator added the numbers.*)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm very fond of that term, thank you very much. I got involved [with cleft sentences](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/leftovershandout.pdf) a while back, and found I needed a term for the _be_ that divides the two parts. My favorite is [_nobbut_ clefts](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

Comment: @John Lawler Either a comment of mine has been deleted or my watch has stopped.

Comment: I would suggest the former, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [1] *It was the in­ven­tion of the hand-held cal­cu­la­tor that pro­vided*
> *the orig­i­nal tech­nol­ogy for the present gen­er­a­tion of small but*
> *pow­er­ful com­put­ers*.

I can easily see why you think it's an extraposition construction. The combination of "it" as subject and what appears to be a content (*that*) clause serve to make it look, at least superficially, like one.

But it differs from extraposition in that the final element is not a content clause, not a potential replacement for "it".

In fact, it's an *it*-cleft construction, where "it" is a meaningless dummy subject and the final element (the *that* clause) is a relative clause. The more basic non-cleft version of your example is:

> [2] *The in­ven­tion of the hand-held cal­cu­la­tor pro­vided the*
> *orig­i­nal tech­nol­ogy for the present gen­er­a­tion of small but*
> *pow­er­ful com­put­ers.*

To form of an *it*-cleft [1] from a syntactically more basic non-cleft [2] we divide it into two parts -- hence the 'cleft' component of the name. One of the two parts, here *the in­ven­tion of the hand-held cal­cu­la­tor*,  is foregrounded, while the other, *pro­vided the orig­i­nal tech­nol­ogy for the present gen­er­a­tion of small but pow­er­ful com­put­ers*, is backgrounded. The foregrounded element functions as complement to "be", and the backgrounded element is expressed in a relative clause, with the foregrounded element as antecedent for the relativised element, "who", "which" etc.

Note, though, that unlike in 'normal' relative constructions, the relative clause in a cleft construction is not a dependent of the antecedent. It doesn't modify / combine with it to form a syntactic unit; rather, it is a postnuclear element appearing at the end of the clause.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Comment: +1 very useful post.